# Use image as convolution kernel

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm currently trying to implement some result of [this paper](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Dekel_On_the_Effectiveness_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf) published by Google on how to remove watermarks from images. I created around 80 pictures with my own watermark (font and crossing lines above the whole picture) and I'm able to detect the edges with the Laplacian filter.

My problem is that the edges are not enough to remove the watermark from the image. When the lines are wider than 1 pixel the edges leave a gap in between. The paper says the following:

> Specifically,
>   for a given watermarked image, we obtain a verbose edge map (using Canny edge detector), and compute its Euclidean distance transform, which is then convolved with the watermark edges (flipped horizontally and vertically) to get the Chamfer distance from each pixel to the closest edge. Lastly, the watermark position is taken to be the pixel with minimum distance in the map.

I can get the distance transform with following code:

```
### Detect water mark edges
imgs = glob.glob("images/*.jpg")
mean = np.zeros((1200, 1600))

for i, filename in enumerate(imgs):
    img = cv2.imread(filename,0)
    mean += cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_64F,ksize=3)

mean /= len(imgs)

#### Edge map & distance transform
img = cv2.imread("images/1.jpg", 0)

can = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)
dist = cv2.distanceTransform(can, cv2.DIST_L2, 3)
```

But how should I do the convolution now? What should be my kernel for this? The lines of my watermark cross the entire picture so the watermark edge image has the same size as my original image.

**EDIT based on @Cris Luengo answer:**

```
_, mean = cv2.threshold(mean, 64, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

meanFFT = np.fft.fft2(mean)
distFFT = np.fft.fft2(dist)

conj = np.conjugate(meanFFT)
res = distFFT * meanFFT

cv2.imwrite('watermark.png', np.fft.ifft(res).real)
```

Comment: maybe some kind of "template" of the watermark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote from the paper that you give says "which is then convolved with the watermark edges (flipped horizontally and vertically)".

A convolution with an image flipped horizontally and vertically is the cross-correlation with that image. Thus, here we are computing the cross-correlation of the distance transform of the edges in the image with the edges in the watermark. The shift for which the cross-correlation is minimal is the shift for which the watermark edges best match the edges in the image.

The watermark edges are obtained using Canny, just like you obtain the edges of the image.

To compute the cross-correlation, use the Fourier domain:

1. Make sure the two images (distance transform and edges of watermark) are the same size. Pad them with zeros to make their sizes match.
2. Compute the FFT of both.
3. Compute the complex conjugate of the FFT of the watermark image (this corresponds to flipping the image vertically and horizontally in the spatial domain).
4. Multiply the two
5. Compute the inverse transform, and crop away the regions that correspond to the padding added to the distance transform image (if any).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! I tried to implement this but this doesn't result in a usefull image. I added my code to the question above. Would be great if you could have a look. My images do have the same size. In step 4 do you mean matrix multiplication or element wise multiplication? Also from the inverse transformation do you keep the real or imaginary part?

Comment: @Cilenco: Oh, you are using `mean` as your template? I was wondering why you computed that... I think the paper is based on the presumption that you have an image of the watermark by itself. The way you compute `mean` means that the watermark is at the same spot in every image? Then what is the point in trying to locate it? This cross-correlation process is meant to find where in the image the watermark is.

Comment: That said, `conj = np.conjugate(meanFFT); res = distFFT * meanFFT` should be `res = distFFT * np.conjugate(meanFFT)`. You're computing the convolution, not the cross-correlation. A typo I presume. The result should be real-valued, check that the imaginary component is just numeric inaccuracy (values 1e-14 or so), then discard the imaginary part and keep the real part.

Comment: Thank you I will try this. _The way you compute mean means that the watermark is at the same spot in every image? Then what is the point in trying to locate it?_ Yeah that's true but I thought without this step I only have the edges of the watermark (`mean`) and not the whole watermark itself. I later have to solve for the alpha and the edges are not enough for that right?

Comment: @Cilenco: I clicked on your link there, and had a quick look through the paper. It seems they use the median of the x and y gradients independently to determine what the watermark is. I don’t understand why this would work, but I don’t have time to read the paper in detail. Note that you use the mean of the Laplace, both operations are different from what is described in the paper. You should try to follow the paper to the letter, and only vary from that once your have it working as intended. Otherwise you’ll never know what is wrong!

Comment: Good point! I only used the mean instead of the median because it is easier to calculate. For the median I have to keep all matrices in memory to sort them and then use the mean value. Let's say I calculate x and y gradients independently with the sobel operator. For `k` images I then have `2k` values for each pixel. Should I take the median of theses `2k` values or how is this ment?

Comment: The median of the k images for the x-gradient and the median of the k images for the y gradient.

Comment: But this would result in two different images.

Comment: @Cilenco: yes, and then they apply some form of integral (as an optimization method I seem to remember?) to derive the watermark image. Sorry, the method in the paper is quite involved, definite not as simple as what you’re trying to do, and I don’t have time to sit and read this paper to understand what they do and how. If you really want to implement this paper, you’ll have to read through the paper carefully and really make sure you understand it all. I can’t help you with that.